# Emscripten copy/paste clipboard

Tags: c++, sdl, emscripten

Is there a possibility in emscripten to copy/paste text?

Emscripten has SDL support.

But using `SDL_GetClipboardText()`, `SDL_SetClipboardText()` seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have released a small C++ header-only library to easily handle copy and paste in the browser: https://github.com/Armchair-Software/emscripten-browser-clipboard

Example usage, handling paste with a callback:

```cpp
#include <emscripten_browser_clipboard.h>

// ...

  // set a lambda as a callback to handle paste data:
  emscripten_browser_clipboard::paste([](std::string const &paste_data, void *callback_data [[maybe_unused]]){
    std::cout << "Copied clipboard data: " << paste_data << std::endl;
  });
```

Sending copy data with a callback:

```cpp
#include <emscripten_browser_clipboard.h>

// ...

  std::string my_content{"This is something for the clipboard."};

  // set a lambda as a callback to handle copy events:
  emscripten_browser_clipboard::copy([](void *callback_data [[maybe_unused]]){
    return my_content.c_str();
  });
```

Sending copy data directly:

```cpp
#include <emscripten_browser_clipboard.h>

// ...

  std::string my_content{"This is something for the clipboard."};

  emscripten_browser_clipboard::copy(my_content); // attempt to set clipboard content immediately
```

Comment: Dear Riot, first and foremost: THX for the effort. I tried to use it with my ImPlot+HelloImgui app and I was only half successful.  I can cut text from the app and paste it outside the browser, e.g. in a terminal. I cannot paste in the app anything that was cut outside, i.e. I cannot cut something in a terminal and paste it in the wasm app.  I did try using https instead http to soothe Firefox, yet no dice.  Do you happen to have any hints up your sleeve?

Comment: I think it works, it's just something on my side. The paste event is fired by middle trackpad button on my laptop, not by Ctrl+V. That setts the data. The next Ctrl+V pastes it in the Imgui wasm app. So I have to hit middle button and then Ctrl+V to have it pasted correctly.  So this is clearly some race / listener shenanigans I will deal with.  Thanks again for the header file.

Comment: @MichalKarmBabacek it seems many browsers specifically need a ctrl-v keypress to paste from external sources, rather than any "internal" paste method such as mouse clicks, usually for security reasons - to avoid websites "stealing" paste data inadvertently.  It may be a behaviour your specific browser allows you to configure.  You can always check that the callback itself is being fired, and with what data, using the paste example code in this answer and looking in the console, which can help to debug the situation.

Comment: Mouse "middle button' click makes the functions in your header file called, i.e. the "paste" event is fired in JS, all the way to the lambda in emscripten_browser_clipboard::paste( being called.      Ctrl+V on the other hand does not trigger "paste" event in JS, although it does make `get_content_for_imgui` to be called.    So far no idea why there is no "paste" event and the listener is not called in the browser on plain Ctrl+V. I will share it here when I find out. The browser being up to date Firefox on Linux.

Comment: When I have this on a plain site:
```
document.addEventListener(
"paste", (event) => {
console.log('paste event');
});
```
It's both Ctrl+V and mouse middle button logging "paste event". On my ImGui site, it's only the middle button :-D

Comment: Followup: https://github.com/pthom/hello_imgui/issues/3#issuecomment-1564536870